# PayU Payment Gateway - I can't use API PayU Version 2

Tags: php, api, payu

I use Laravel 5 and via composer I install the **Official OpenPayU PHP Library 2.2** (https://github.com/PayU/openpayu_php)

But this require: MerchantPosId, SignatureKey, OauthClientId and OauthClienteSecret.

And I only have in my merchant admin panel: Api_key, API_login, Public_key, Merchant_Id.

I related:

- MerchantPosId = Merchant_Id
- SignatureKey = Api_key
- OauthClientId = Merchant_Id
- OauthClienteSecret = API_login | Api_key

But not working the method **create** or others methods of the class **OpenPayU_Order**
I get the error:

> Oauth error: [code=401], [message=invalid_client - Can't find
>   oauthClient with clientId = 123445]

Will my settings are wrong? Is it necessary to require new?

Comment: did got solution?

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding a new POS in PayU admin panel, you have to choose "REST API" over "Classic API". Classic API doesn't use oauthClient, so your client_id won't be found.